# Unable to paginate with Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I scrape a website with Scrapy. My problem is that the pagination is using javascript. So I can't loop through a link.
I try to figure that out with Selenium but I have multiple errors with a lot of `(referer: None)` or `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class="btn-next"]/a"`

My spider code:

```
    import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from lp_spider.items import AnnonceItem
from selenium import webdriver


class AnnonceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lp_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "lp_spider", "json/input/db_scrap_url_lp_js_10000_reduced2.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['url_lp'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//li[@class='btn-next']/a")

            try:
                item = response.meta['item']
                item['results'] = []

                for caritem in response.css("li.li-result"):
                    data = AnnonceItem()
                    data["marque"] = caritem.css("span.brand::text").extract_first(
                    )
                    item['results'].append(data)

                yield item

                next.click()

            except:
                break

        self.driver.close()
```

A screenshot of the pagination's HTML: 
[image]

EDIT: I post the XHR of the console when I click on the next button:
[image]
[image]

Comment: you'll need to use a WebDriverWait with an ExpectedCondition for any elements you find via Selenium.  It doesn't seem like there will be a pageLoad here so Selenium won't wait unless you tell it.  Looks like you are intercepting the JSON?... so maybe all you need is to wait for the next button.  At some point the client side script is going to re-write those buttons and during that time you may find it's not available.

Comment: i'd check xhr and make sure you cant get them without JS

Comment: I edited my question and posted the XHR

Comment: Combining Scrapy and Selenium can be tricky. See https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium

Comment: So what's the better solution ? Stick with Selenium, use Splash or there is a way to only use HTML and Scrapy